# Compatibility of SubSequence indices

Tags: swift, string, generics, collections

For most Swift `Collections`, indices of a `Collection's` `SubSequence` are compatible for use with the base `Collection`.

```
func foo<T: Collection>(_ buffer: T) -> T.Iterator.Element
    where T.Index == T.SubSequence.Index
{
    let start = buffer.index(buffer.startIndex, offsetBy: 2)
    let end = buffer.index(buffer.startIndex, offsetBy: 3)
    let sub = buffer[start ... end]
    return buffer[sub.startIndex]
}
```

This works fine for most collections:

```
print(foo([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])) // 2
```

And even for `String.UTF8View`:

```
print(foo("01234".utf8) - 0x30 /* ASCII 0 */) // 2
```

But when using `String.CharacterView`, things start breaking:

```
print(foo("01234".characters)) // "0"
```

For the CharacterView, SubSequences create completely independent instances, i.e. Index starts again at 0. To convert back to a main String index, one has to use the `distance` function and add that to the `startIndex` of the `SubSequence` in the main `String`.

```
func foo<T: Collection>(_ buffer: T) -> T.Iterator.Element
    where T.Index == T.SubSequence.Index, T.SubSequence: Collection, T.SubSequence.IndexDistance == T.IndexDistance
{
    let start = buffer.index(buffer.startIndex, offsetBy: 2)
    let end = buffer.index(buffer.startIndex, offsetBy: 3)
    let sub = buffer[start ... end]

    let subIndex = sub.startIndex
    let distance = sub.distance(from: sub.startIndex, to: subIndex)
    let bufferIndex = buffer.index(start, offsetBy: distance)
    return buffer[bufferIndex]
}
```

With this, all three examples now correctly print 2.

---

- Why are String SubSequence indices not compatible with their base String? As long as everything is immutable, it doesn't make sense to me why Strings are a special case, even with all the Unicode stuff. I've also noticed that substring functions return Strings and not Slices as most other collections do. However, substrings are still documented to be return in O(1). Strange magic.
- Is there a way to constraint a generic function to restrict to collections where the SubSequence indices are compatible with the base Sequence?
- Can one even assume that SubSequence indices are compatible for non-String collections, or is this just a coincidence, and one should always use `distance(from:to:)` to convert indices?

Comment: That has been discussed on the Swift mailing list, and there is a proposal to fix that for character views or collections in general. I'll see if I find the link.

Comment: With "fixing", do you mean adjusting CharacterViews to match the regular Collections, or do you mean adjusting Collection indices to no longer be compatible between SubSequences and base Sequences?

Comment: Here is the bug report https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1927, and here the pull request for fixing it https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/4896.

Comment: Thanks for that! If you resubmit this comment as answer, I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That has been [discussed on swift-evolution](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20160627/022460.html), filed as bug report 
[SR-1927 – Subsequences of String Views don’t behave correctly](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1927) and recently been fixed 
in [StringCharacterView.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/StringCharacterView.swift)
with
[commit](https://github.com/apple/swift/commit/c2bc72d9d6f096a81d0a483113518c297793be49#diff-e3e73041cb4200c0c609eaf60d5c2754).

With that fix `String.CharacterView` behaves
like other collections in that its slices should use the same indices for the same elements as the original collection.